# Invalid AAB file type While Uploading to Google Play

Tags: android, android-app-bundle, android-developer-api

When I try to import a Bundle application (.AAB), Android tells me that the ZIP file is invalid, we followed the same steps presented in the documentation but nothing works.

What I need to do?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlHXC.png)

I have this message : You have imported an invalid ZIP archive file.

Comment: how much abis type in your apk ?

Comment: Where Can i Find that?

Comment: Are you able to rename the .aab as a .zip and open it with your favourite ZIP archive tool? Also how did you build the .aab file in the first place? Do you have some post-processing tools or did you modify the file in any way after it was generated by the build system?

Comment: I generated it the same way as the following YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9sIbnVR5JQ 
I did not touch the file after generation
@Pierre

Comment: First, I designed a functional APK on any type of Android that I tested and validated, then I transposed it into an AAB version in the same way as presented in the documentations. @NikunjParadva

Comment: What about my first question?

Comment: @Pierre I can't open the file if I rename it to zip

Comment: I suspect the file is thus being modified between the time it's generated by Studio and when you upload it to the Play Console.

Comment: It is the following problem that I do not understand: Once generated I put it directly on the console from the generation directory of the aab @Pierre

Comment: From what you said, the file is not a valid zip file so the issue is either in Studio or in your setup (maybe some plugins interfering?). Consider filing a bug in Studio providing your AGP and Studio versions with a sample project to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Finally, I found the solution, thank you very much for your help.

I started again the manipulation with a new Android key generation. @Pierre